# How does this character suddenly catch fire?

Tags: plot-explanation, maps-to-the-stars

Near the end of the film *Maps to the Stars*,

> Cristina Weiss

is out by the swimming pool when she suddenly erupts into flames. I never understood how/why that happens - is it some sort of accident? Does she perform self-immolation?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Jon Campfens](https://cinefex.com/blog/maps-to-the-stars/), co-founder of Switch VFX:

> During the sequence, **Dr. Stafford Weiss discovers that his wife, Christina, has set herself on fire.** He proceeds to push her into their swimming pool with a deck-chair to try and save her. Beau Parsons, one of our on-set supervisors, attended the shoot along with Brandon Rogers, a member of our CG team and lead for the department that would be using Fume FX.
>
> *What direction did you receive from David Cronenberg regarding the action by the pool?*
>
> It was expressed to us by David during the prep stages that the performance comes before anything else. Despite our suggestions that shooting fire elements or using a stunt double would provide more realistic fire, **David wanted to go the CG route in order to preserve Olivia’s performance.** I am not a great lover of CG fire, but it was the only way to proceed in order to get what David wanted. **It was important to him that the audience knew it was really her and not a stunt double using fire retarder** – which has a very reflective quality to it.

---

I presume the reason why she set herself on fire is this (from [the plot as described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maps_to_the_Stars#Plot)):

> Agatha visits her mother, Cristina, and reveals that before she set the fire she had discovered that **her parents were brother and sister**, making Agatha and Benjie children of incest.

(Her parents are Dr. Stafford Weiss and Cristina.)

---

[For some insight](http://www.larsenonfilm.com/maps-to-the-stars):

> Written by Bruce Wagner and directed by David Cronenberg, *Maps to the Stars* turns on **three central motifs: incest, fire and disfigured flesh**. (Did I mention it was directed by David Cronenberg?) According to the movie, **familiarity breeds self-annihilation** – indeed, for one character, it arrives via self-immolation.

---

Her death is also [a combination of various motifs](https://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/id/eprint/13844/3/13844.pdf) running through the film:

> These ghost are in the(ir) elements, fire and water, death by drowning
> (little Micah, played by Domenic Ricci) and death by fire (Havana’s
> mother, Agatha and Benji); Christina even manages to combine both.

Plus a reference to another classic movie:

> The corpse in the pool alludes, of course, to ***Sunset Boulevard***’s
> (1950, dir. **Billy Wilder**) famous opening scene, the floating body who
> is also the narrator, recounting this story of mental disintegration
> and social corruption, film noir’s equivalent to the Gothic novel’s
> skeleton in the closet or the waxwork of a decaying body behind the
> veil in **Ann Radcliffe**’s ***The Mysteries of Udolpho*** (1794). And just as
> in Radcliffe’s novel, in *Maps to the Stars* we never see the body of
> the burnt/drowned Christina in the pool.